# Is there a way to update the dojo tree item id with the id come from database?

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo tree that its nodes are created temporary in memory. I assigned every new node an id by timestamp like this:
var newID = new Date().getTime(). 
This new node will associate with a form to control its info. My expected is: when the form is submit, the new id came from the database will replace the timestamp id above. How can I do this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How are you submitting your form?  What is returned from the web server once your form is submitted?  Can you provide some example code snippets?